# Wordpress Permalink Settings and htaccess the posts not available

Tags: wordpress, configuration

I have posted 3 posts to my WordPress blog. And, initially, I used default links for those, like

http://example.com/?p=74

then I decide to change this URL to Permalink, in Permalink Settings in WordPress panel.

I have provided access to my .htaccess file for worpress, so it ables to fill up this file by some content as soon as I change the settings. So, that's ok.

After, I changed the setting to use perm-link-pattern like this: /%postname%/

1.htaccess was changed by WordPress

2 the links to the posts were changed in the page

3.**BUT** when clicking on these modified links it **goes to the udefined content** (there is **not** any page by this url) EVEN if create new post (but not just using old one).

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. There are 1000 articles about this over the internet, but everything about details...

So, for my case:

1. sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
2. and make sure that you have 'AllowOverride All'

> ```
> ...
>  <Directory /var/www/my-site>
>                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>                 AllowOverride All
>                 Order allow,deny
>                 allow from all
>  </Directory>
>  ...
> ```

then restart the Apache, and everything working.